# Mysql time error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good Morning guys,
i wanna insert different times in my mysql-table.(no dates!)

```
  mysql> insert into table zeiten(erste_abfahrt,letzte_abfahrt,linie) values ('05:08:00','23:56:00',11);
```

erste_abfahrt and letzte_abfahrt are from type time and Linie from type int.

I don´t find my mistake.Please help me.

Best regards

Comment: change `insert into table zeiten` to `insert into zeiten`

Comment: show the ddl and the error message.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thx, write it as an answer and you get the star. ;) best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the insert commenad

```
insert into table zeiten
```

You dont need `table` here and it should be as

```
insert into zeiten
```